# Safari: window.showModalDialog doubles all key presses (Safari for Windows)

Tags: javascript, safari

I noticed in [this firefox documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.showModalDialog) Safari 5.1 introduces support for a window.showModalDialog() function.  I tried it out, and for some reason all keystrokes in form elements in the modal dialog get doubled up.

You can try it out here (Safari 5.1 or greater for Windows required): http://jsfiddle.net/RF2cV/

*Any* clue how to remedy this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I do not see the effect you describe with Safari 5.0.4 on Windows XP. (It does open the google window, however.)

Comment: Thanks for the extra info Pointy.  I've reproduced the behaviour on Safari 5.1 and 5.1.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: Did anyone every find a resolution to this?

Comment: No luck over here PilotBob.  I made a post on the safari dev forums and it's been left unanswered, with the occasional bump here and there from people asking if it will ever be fixed.  Seems like kind of an important issue!  My company was unable to announce support of our product for Safari on Windows as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed by adding [return false] within document.onkeydown event.

Comment: While doing this fixes it for Safari, it messes up for IE :/ It would be good if we could find one solution that doesn't rely on checking browsers

Comment: Accepted for a valid workaround, thanks.  Although it looks like apple has killed safari for windows forever, so this is less of a problem than it used to be!